# can we create database by gii tool in yii framework

Tags: yii

I am beginner to Yii framework. I want to create a CRUD application. Is it possible to create database by using gii tool in Yii framework or by any other method. please give any  clue. I am searching in tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Gii is for automated tasks, like for creating models and controllers. Normal when i start a new (Yii) project, i wil create the tables through PHPMyAdmin. When the project is copied to a new location, eg test or staging, i do all database migrations via the Yii Migration tool.